text editor for react like megadraft
I need a text editor like megadraft or tiptap which is posted here TipTap example
I need a text editor that will not have a toolbar with buttons. I need a text editor that will have a plus on the left with which you can add an image, video and table and there are little things and so that when selected, you can change the text itself or, let’s say, make it a list
